# Change view controller when WKWebView loaded a specific URL

Tags: swift, wkwebview

I'm currently working on a project developing an app for the iPhone. I used the WKWebView class to access the sign-in form of the website. I made the PHP login form to redirect to a custom web address (www.example.com/successful-login) if the user successfully logins. I tried to change the view controller if the that URL was loaded in WkWebView but the below code didn't work. Any help or suggestions?

```
let myWebView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height))
myWebView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

if let signurl = URL(string:"https://www.example.com/login"){
    let request = URLRequest(url: signurl)
    myWebView.load(request)
}

view.addSubview(myWebView)

var loadedUrl = String()

func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    loadedUrl = myWebView.url?.absoluteString as String!// GETS URL OF CURRENT PAGE LOADED

    if loadedUrl.range(of: "https://www.example.com/successful-login") != nil {
        let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "newViewController") as! CustomViewController
        self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: In the code you provided you forgot to set the `WKNavigationDelegate`: `myWebView.navigationDelegate = self`

Comment: @nathan thanks for the tip. I have set the WKNavigationDelegate but still doesn't change the view. Also I added print(loadedUrl) inside the function too see if it's getting the link  but nothing and this is the console log:
 Unable to copy asset information from https://mesu.apple.com/assets/ for asset type com.apple.MobileAsset.TextInput.SpellChecker